# How to "normalize" json-object from Ajax-call or alter SQL-query

Tags: mysql, ajax, join, each

I have problems formatting a json-object as a result from an Ajax-Call the way I want it. Also I don't know if my approach is the best possible way..

To explain the situation:
Let's say I have names and heights of persons and their favorite colors (which can be several) stored in my db. the tables look like this

```
persons:
+ id |  name  |  height  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1  | peter  |    185    |
| 2  | paul   |    176    |


colors:
+ id |  color  +
++++++++++++++++    
| 1  |  green  |
| 2  |  blue   |
| 3  |  yellow |
| 4  |  red    |


person_color:
+ id | id_person | id_color  +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    
| 1  |     1     |     1     |
| 2  |     1     |     2     |
| 3  |     1     |     3     |
| 4  |     2     |     2     |
| 5  |     2     |     4     |
```

I get the data I need by left-joining the tables like this

```
SELECT id, name, height, colors.color 
    FROM persons
LEFT JOIN person_color 
    ON persons.id = person_color.id_person
LEFT JOIN colors 
    ON person_color.id_color = color.id
```

This all works fine.

Then I json_encode the query-result and hand the object back to the script.

In case of a successful call, I create a html-table by going through the returned object like this

```
var html = "<table>";
$.each(msg) = function(key, val) { 
   html += "<tr>";
   $.each(val) = function(key2, val2){
      html += "<td>+val2+</td>";
   }
   html += "</tr>";
}
html += "</table>";
```

That gives me this table as a result:

```
+ id |  name  |  groesse  |    farbe    +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1  | peter  |    185    |    green    |
| 1  | peter  |    185    |     blue    |
| 1  | peter  |    185    |    yellow   |
| 2  | paul   |    176    |     blue    |
| 2  | paul   |    176    |     red     |
```

So far, so good. But what i want to achieve is to display the result in a form like this:

```
+ id +  name  +  height   +          color          +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    
| 1  | peter  |    185    |   green, blue, yellow   |
| 2  | paul   |    176    |         blue, red       |
```

Shouldn't be too difficult, but I am going in circles..

Also I am not sure whether to change the script creating the html-table, or if there is a clever way to alter the SQL-statement to produce something in the right form.

Any hint to either of this would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Paco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregating function in mysql:

```
SELECT id, name, height, GROUP_CONCAT(colors.color SEPARATOR ', ') as color
    FROM persons
LEFT JOIN person_color 
    ON persons.id = person_color.id_person
LEFT JOIN colors 
    ON person_color.id_color = color.id
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, I was just reading about that too. Seems like the right direction.

But this gives me back only one line with all the colors of all rows in one field

Comment: `| 1  | peter  |    185    |   green, blue, yellow, blue, red   |`

Comment: Noooo my mistake! I forgot the group by...
Thanks @Serge, you made my day
:)